# sling servlet giving error when called from cq5 dialog for dynamic select dropdown

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

I created a servlet that returns a JSON containing options to add in a dropdown. I set this servlet's path using the `options` parameter under the node.

The servlet is called by the dropdown. I can also test it manually via the URL: `localhost:4502/bin/myServlet/`. It calls my servlet and prints the JSON result. However along with that  there is also an error message:

> {"text":"abcd","value":"xyz","text":"abcd","value":"xyz"}
>
> Method GET not supported
>
> Cannot serve request to /bin/tagFinder in com.marsh.newsLatest.servlets.TagLocatorServlet
>   Request Progress:
>
> ```
>  0 (2015-01-15 19:40:47) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
>  0 (2015-01-15 19:40:47) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
>  0 (2015-01-15 19:40:47) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/bin/tagFinder
> ```
>
> (...)

How can I get rid of the error?

The servlet code can be found below:

```
package com.abc.newsLatest.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.io.JSONWriter;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/tagFinder",methods="get")
public class TagLocatorServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3960692666512058118L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("in get method ");
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(response.getWriter());

        try {
            writer.object();
            // {
            writer.key("text").value("allhad");
            writer.key("value").value("nilekar");

            writer.key("text").value("allhad");
            writer.key("value").value("nilekar");


            writer.endObject(); // }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.doGet(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("in post");
        this.doGet(request, response);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is produced by the `doGet()` method defined in the [superclass](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/servlets/SlingSafeMethodsServlet.html#doGet(org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest,%20org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse)). Remove the last line from your `doGet()` implementation and the error should disappear:

```
super.doGet(request, response);
```